# Responsive iframe still has scroll bar and not scaling

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to create a responsive iframe but I still get scroll bars on 2 sides and the interactive image isn't scaling...

I think the interactive html (a map with hover states/pop ups) was generated using an Abode product

This is where the iframe lives:

```
<div class="resp-container"><iframe class="resp-iframe" title="Sample" src="sample.html"></iframe></div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.resp-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.resp-iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    display:block;
}
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong? If I change the height to 'auto' then the iframe goes to 150px for some reason even though the canvas is 800px

Many thanks in advance

Comment: There is nothing "responsive" about your CSS. Where are your media-queries?

Answer (score 0):

Try remaking your iframe with the following reference. It worked great for me:

[https://css-tricks.com/responsive-iframes/#:~:text=The%20best%20trick%20for%20responsive,order%20to%20fill%20the%20area](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-iframes/#:%7E:text=The%20best%20trick%20for%20responsive,order%20to%20fill%20the%20area).

The above works best. I hope it helped you solve the problem

Comment: Please do your best at translating that page to an answer without external references.  While the answer may work the link may not in the future.